# API to use deault Web Cam?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm working on a Win32 application in C++ and would like to add the ability to output the default web cam onto the screen. I was wondering if there was a Win32 API for this, or a way to do this without coding the whole thing.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is really simple with capCreateCaptureWindow.  That googles really well, you'll have no trouble finding code samples.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend DirectShow. capXXX API is really old and obsolete. OpenCV is based on Win32 API.

Answer (score 0):

Using [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) you can access webcam.